# Knowing which resources are loaded in the ADT Layout tool

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I know which resources are currently loaded by the ADT Layout Editor, when I am changing the target screen size. 
Since there is no proper and accurate listing on which resources are used I thought the ADT eclipse editor could easily tell me which modifiers are used for the individual screen/device selections. Does ADT provide this information, and how can I get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, clicking on the target device chooser in the Layout Editor -> define own ... brings up a list of modifiers each device is dedicated to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately ADT doesnt say anything about it. But to see which layout loaded, put and TextView in your layout.xml for each screen size.

For example

layout-ldpi/main.xml -> android:text="ldpi"

layout-mdpi/main.xml -> android:text="mdpi"

layout-hdpi/main.xml -> android:text="hdpi"

layout-xhdpi/main.xml -> android:text="xhdpi"

And you can see which layout has been loaded

if You use one layout, put images to your drawable

drawable-ldpi/screensize.png

drawable-mdpi/screensize.png

drawable-hdpi/screensize.png

drawable-xhdpi/screensize.png

And put and test image to your layout and give its backgroud this image, when you change screen size you will see that image will be changed. So you can understand which lyout has been loaded.

layout/main.xml -> android:background="@drawable/screensize"

you can use the image below,

[image: ldpi]

[image: mdpi]

[image: hdpi]

[image: xhdpi]

Comment: Well my concern goes towards screen modifiers like largen. small, normal, and I I am  not changing the layout I am only changing the dimensions in the values folder to minimize the layout copies

Comment: Not realy, this still means I need to check every other modifier by using such helper resources, which is not really convinient. I am search more of a magical right click option which shows me the path to the defined resource (not just drawable, but also dimensions and styles etc)

Comment: Sorry i dont know  there are any tool to do this ?